# Cannot Read File in Working Directory

Tags: java, io

I am learning basic I/O for java, and the following example is from [Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html). The program flows a FileNotFound exception. I place the file under the working directory, and I also tried to use absolute file path, and the result is still the same. I use Eclipse to write the code. What could be causing this exception? Thanks

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyBytes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
            out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");
            int c;

            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the error message include the full path of the file that isn't found?

Comment: ... and can you share the stacktrace please?

Comment: ...and do you actually have a file called "xanadu.txt"?

Comment: To find out exactly where Java is looking for `xanadu.txt`, you may want to invoke a code like this: `System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath())`, provided that you wrap your `xanadu.txt` as a File, like so: `new File("xanadu.txt")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of things that can cause that exception. Here are a few things to try:

-Verify that Xanadu.txt is a file using the `isFile()` method. If it returns false then you know where your problem is.

-Try placing the file in the project directory.

-Given that you already tried using the absolute file path I would also make sure that your program has permission to look at and write to the file. To check if eclipse has permission go to the properties of your file

Comment: As @ifly6 said I use `System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath())` to check where the program is looking for the file, and it turns out that the path is the same as where my file locates. `isFile()` returns false but this is a .txt file with only two lines of characters, I don't know why this is not considered a normal file

Comment: @Gbldgett It returns false. If Eclipse doesn't have permission to read the file, what kind of Exception would I get?

Comment: It is my fault, I named it as xanadu.txt. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Place the file `xanadu.txt` in the project directory and `FileNotFoundException` will go away.

`FileInputStream` will expect an existing input file.

Answer (score 0):

The code probably isn't being executed from the path you expected.

You should use the `home` folder for this. `C:\Users\<User Name>` on windows and `/home/<User Name>` on linux. You can create a folder there to put your files.

To get the `home` directory, you can use this.

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

Other solution would be to pack the files inside the JAR.

If you want to debug your problem, you can get the current directory like this.

```
<Your Class>.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
```